Dapper QueryAsync not returning some SQL rows when using UNION ALL
I'm converting a Visual Basic API to .NET 8 using the same SQL Server query with the same parameters, and I noticed that some rows are not being displayed in the response object.
The query uses UNION ALL and the missing rows only exist in the second SELECT statement (Deleted_Appointments table):
SELECT
    A.Appointment_Id,
    A.Appointment_Date,
    C.Client_Id,
    C.Name AS Client_Name,
    S.Service_Id,
    S.Description AS Service_Name,
    CO.Name AS Company_Name,
    CO.Address AS Company_Address,
    '' AS Deleted_By
FROM Appointments A (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN Appointment_Services ApS (NOLOCK) ON ApS.Appointment_Id = A.Appointment_Id
LEFT JOIN Services S (NOLOCK) ON S.Service_Id = ApS.Service_Id
LEFT JOIN Clients C (NOLOCK) ON C.Client_Id = A.Client_Id
LEFT JOIN Companies CO (NOLOCK) ON CO.Company_Id = A.Company_Id
LEFT JOIN Users U (NOLOCK) ON U.Id = A.User_Id
WHERE A.Appointment_Date BETWEEN '07/01/2024 00:00:00' AND '07/31/2024 23:59:59'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    DA.Appointment_Id,
    DA.Appointment_Date,
    C.Client_Id,
    C.Name AS Client_Name,
    S.Service_Id,
    S.Description AS Service_Name,
    CO.Name AS Company_Name,
    CO.Address AS Company_Address,
    U.Name AS Deleted_By
FROM Deleted_Appointments DA (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN Deleted_Appointment_Services DAS (NOLOCK) ON DAS.Appointment_Id = DA.Appointment_Id
LEFT JOIN Services S (NOLOCK) ON S.Service_Id = DAS.Service_Id
LEFT JOIN Clients C (NOLOCK) ON C.Client_Id = DA.Client_Id
LEFT JOIN Companies CO (NOLOCK) ON CO.Company_Id = DA.Company_Id
LEFT JOIN Users U (NOLOCK) ON U.Id = DA.User_Id
WHERE DA.Appointment_Date BETWEEN '07/01/2024 00:00:00' AND '07/31/2024 23:59:59'

The C# code using Dapper's QueryAsync to retrieve the data:
public async Task<List<AppointmentsResponse>> GetAppointments(
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate,
    List<long> ClientIds,
    int Status,
    bool IsMobile
)
{
    var sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.AppendLine(/* the above query */);

    // These statements are repeated for the
    // second SELECT statement with the correct
    // table alias. I know... bad code. It will be fixed.
    if (IsMobile)
        sql.AppendLine("AND A.IsMobile = 1");

    if (ClientIds.Count > 0)
    {
        string inClause = string.Join(", ", ClientIds);
        sql.AppendLine($"AND A.Client_Id IN ({inClause})");
    }

    if (Status > 0)
        sql.AppendLine($"AND A.Appointment_Status = {Status}");

    using var con = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
    var result = await con.QueryAsync<AppointmentsResponse>(sql.ToString(), new { startDate, endDate });

    return result.ToList();
}

I've tried using foreach to loop through each row and check if they were being returned correctly, and the missing rows are skipped entirely. I've also tried using QueryMultipleAsync but the result remained the same.
I've compared the same query with the one from the Visual Basic API and they both return the data as it should when executed in Microsoft's SSMS.
The VB implementation also returns it correctly.
EDIT: Added the complete query and C# parameters for better context.

The nolock hints aren't the automatic "go faster" trick you may have heard. You should remove them. Also, the format for the timestamps is wrong. SQL Server can be particular about this. It should be either 20240701 00:00:00 or 2024-07-01T00:00:00. Oh, and instead of 23:59:59 for the end of the range, you should use an exclusive boundary (< instead of <=) for the start of the next day.

But as to the question: I don't really think this will work, but just to be sure, try wrapping the whole UNION in an outer SELECT: SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ... FROM ... UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM ... ) t

Oh, it there's no ON for the JOINs. This could be an oversite, but it could be more.

Using a StringBuilder for an SQL query is a red flag for me. Are you building it dynamically, if so why? Can you not use proper parameters instead? If it's dynamic can you show the full code that builds it?

@JoelCoehoorn Tried wrapping it as well as using a CTE, but neither of them worked. Running each statement separately in SSMS still displays the data correctly.
As for the NOLOCK hints, I'll keep that in mind. I just left it in query since I basically just copy and pasted it from VB.NET.

@Charlieface I am building it dynamically. I've edited the question with the full parameters.

You have injection right there. It should be sql.AppendLine("AND A.Client_Id IN @ClientIds"); and sql.AppendLine("AND A.Appointment_Status = @Status"); and then you pass them in as part of the parameters new { startDate, endDate, Status, ClientIds }

I don't see any parameters in the SQL query. You are using datetime literals, the format of which depends on the specified language.

Those AppendLine() calls are broken, for two reasons. One, they don't do query parameterization. This is a HUGE DEAL! Second, they don't put any whitespace between the end of the prior clause and the start of the new clause! You need a space at the front of the strings to append.

I'm pretty sure your c# code has some bugs, looking at the structure of it, you probably forgot to add UNION ALL or the whole second sql part altogether. Or, you're connected to wrong database that doesn't have the Deleted-data, because you're working on some test environment. Or something else, but sanitized query won't really help us help you. Voting on closing by lack of info. If you want to debug it further, trace the queries ran when your code is running and see if there's something fishy going on

Won't fully solve the issue, so just community wiki, but I'd write the SQL more like this:
SELECT
    A.Appointment_Id,
    A.Appointment_Date,
    -- other columns
FROM Appointments A 
LEFT JOIN Some_Table ST ON ST.Id = A.Appointment_Id
-- more tables using LEFT JOIN
WHERE A.Appointment_Date >= '20240701 00:00:00' AND A.Appointment_Date < '20240801 00:00:00'

UNION ALL

SELECT
    DA.Appointment_Id,
    DA.Appointment_Date,
    -- other columns
FROM Deleted_Appointments DA (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN Some_Table ST ON ST.Id = DA.Appointment_Id
-- more tables using LEFT JOIN
WHERE DA.Appointment_Date >= '20240701 00:00:00' AND DA.Appointment_Date < '20240801 00:00:00'

It might be further tempting to do the union (and date filters) on the Appointments and Deleted_Appointments tables in a subquery or CTE before the joins. This could simplify the query. But without knowing indexes, the contents of the rest of the query, and selectivity or size of those source tables vs the rest of the data it's hard to know if it would be helpful.
Oh, and don't look past removing the (NOLOCK). It's not my first guess, but it is actually possible this was the source of your issue.
